# Нужны ли запятые до и после частицы "ой"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Прерывать монолог Елены(,) ой(,) как не хотелось.**

В предложении разговорного характера нужны ли запятые до и после частицы "ой"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**В данном предложении частица "ой" пишется без запятых.**

Внутри цельных сочетаний ох (ух, ой) как (какой) (в значении «очень, весьма, страшно», «замечательный, изумительный, ужасный»), а также цельных сочетаний ах ты, ах вы, ах он, ух ты, эх ты, ай да, ах и, эх и, ух и, эй и, ох эти, эк его и т.п. запятая не ставится, например: ...Подчас в каждом приятном слове ее торчала ух какая булавка (Гоголь); Самонадеянности море ох как не любит! (Л. Соболев); ***Мы могли бы получить ой какие увечья*** (Д. Бедный); Это, брат, ух как горько и ух как подло (Гл. Успенский); Ах ты жестокий! Ах он лиса! Ах они плуты прожженные! Ох эти сплетницы! Эх эти шалунишки! Эх и пляски! Ух и лошадь! Ай да Михаил Андреевич, настоящий цыган! (Л. Толстой); Ай да молодец мичман! (Станюкович); Эк его разобрало! (Гоголь); Эк ты напугал меня... (Мамин-Сибиряк). Ср. в предложениях с повторяющимися словами: Тяжко ему, ох тяжко! Достанется тебе на орехи, ух достанется! Хочется его подразнить, ой хочется! Приятно на солнышке, ах приятно!

Справочник Розенталя

Answer (score 2):

Прерывать монолог Елены ой как (= очень) не хотелось.

**Не нужны запятые**, "ой как" употреблено в значении усилительной частицы.

Пример из Нацкорпуса: Ой, как не хотелось идти на уступки! [Юлий Даниэль. Письма из заключения (1966-1970)]

Думаю, что запятую здесь лучше тоже не ставить, однако при наличии паузы "ой" является междометием, запятая ставится.